# Django: Get UTC Timezone

Tags: python, django

This seems extremely simple, but I cannot find a simple explanation: How can I get the UTC timezone to pass here? I want to pass GMT / UTC specifically.

```
from django.utils import timezone
timezone.make_aware(datetime.fromtimestamp(sometimestamp), timezone=???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Python 3.4, a UTC object is in the standard library as [`datetime.timezone.utc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc); you don't need any django-specific functions:

```
import datetime
sometimestamp = 1598992554
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sometimestamp, tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Prior to Python 3.4, most projects used [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) with its `pytz.utc`.

Answer (score 0):

As per: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone

Selecting timezone is used by `pytz` module and can be seen in official docs as well:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.make_aware

Hence get timezone by:

```
import pytz

tz = pytz.timezone('<string>')
```

Timezone list can be confirmed from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

And then use it in `make_aware` method